# GWT superdevmode sourcemaps wrong after recompile

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

When debugging in Chrome DevTools, after a CodeServer recompile(caused by a web browser refresh), the breakpoints fire inside the generated javascript code instead of the Java code.
I've also set the user.agent to safari to have only 1 permutation.

Any idea why the issue with debugger?

Each time a recompile happens, CodeServer generates a new compile- folder, which seems to contain another set of sourcemaps.
Also, clearing the web browser caches seems to help, sometimes the breakpoints are triggering in Java code, but not always.

Environment:

- GWT 2.8 with SuperDevMode
- Google Chrome 51.0.2704.106 m

Comment: GWT 2.8 is still on RC2. Did you post this issue at the [Google Groups GWT Contributors](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/Google-Web-Toolkit-Contributors) or the [Github issues page](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues)?

Comment: not yet, it'd be nice to provide a use case to reproduce it but it only happens in specific scenarios - i.e. when embedding under 2 levels of iframes but only when the whole application is started -- error is not there when running just that module in isolation even when under 2 levels of iframes